# Python smpplib truncating smpp credentials

Tags: python-3.x, smpp

I am using Python SMPP lib to send a SMS. When I try to connect to SmppServer with a longer credentials the username and password are getting truncated and authorisation is failing.

Auth failing case:
   - Username/password longer than 16 char length

Passing case:
   - Username/password not longer than 16 char

So because of the above observation I am sure there is no issue with the SMMPP gateway. The gateway I am trying to communicate itself accepts of username/password of any length.

The following is my code which wraps the smpplib in to a custom class:

```
import smpplib
import smpplib.gsm

from smpplib.client import Client


class SmppClientConfig(object, ):

    def __init__(self, host, port, username, password, source, target, on_delivered_cb, on_sent_cb):
        self.HOST = host
        self.PORT = port
        self.USERNAME = username
        self.PASSWORD = password
        self.SOURCE = source
        self.TARGET = target
        self.ON_RECEIVED_CALLBACK = on_sent_cb
        self.ON_DELIVERED_CALLBACK = on_delivered_cb


class SmppSenderClient(object):

    def __init__(self, config: SmppClientConfig):
        print('Creating SMPP client config with host: ' + config.HOST + ' port: ' + str(config.PORT))

        self._config = config
        self._client = Client(config.HOST, config.PORT)
        self._on_delivered_callback = config.ON_DELIVERED_CALLBACK
        self._on_received_callback = config.ON_RECEIVED_CALLBACK

        self._init_client()

    def _init_client(self):
        print('Initializing SmppSender client with username: ' + self._config.USERNAME)

        self._register_events()
        self._client.connect()
        self._client.bind_transmitter(system_id=self._config.USERNAME, password=self._config.PASSWORD)

    def _register_events(self):
        print('Registering Smpp events')
        self._client.set_message_sent_handler(self._config.ON_DELIVERED_CALLBACK)
        self._client.set_message_received_handler(self._config.ON_RECEIVED_CALLBACK)

    def send_message(self, message: str):
        print('Sending SMS message to target: ' + self._config.TARGET)
        parts, encoding_flag, msg_type_flag = smpplib.gsm.make_parts(message)

        for part in parts:
            self._client.send_message(
                source_addr_ton=smpplib.consts.SMPP_TON_INTL,
                source_addr_npi=smpplib.consts.SMPP_NPI_ISDN,
                source_addr=self._config.SOURCE,

                dest_addr_ton=smpplib.consts.SMPP_TON_INTL,
                dest_addr_npi=smpplib.consts.SMPP_NPI_ISDN,
                destination_addr=self._config.TARGET,
                short_message=part,

                data_coding=encoding_flag,
                esm_class=msg_type_flag,
                registered_delivery=True,
            )
```

I am not sure if it's an expected behaviour of the library or a limitation. I have tried the find the documentation for this lib but could not find anything other than [this](https://github.com/lavvy/celleter).

Please advise if you experience a similar issue any work around possible or if this is expected behaviour in SMPP protocol (which very unlikely).

Update:
I found the limitation in the source code:

```
class BindTransmitter(Command):
    """Bind as a transmitter command"""

    params = {
        'system_id': Param(type=str, max=16),
        'password': Param(type=str, max=9),
        'system_type': Param(type=str, max=13),
        'interface_version': Param(type=int, size=1),
        'addr_ton': Param(type=int, size=1),
        'addr_npi': Param(type=int, size=1),
        'address_range': Param(type=str, max=41),
    }

    # Order is important, but params dictionary is unordered
    params_order = (
        'system_id', 'password', 'system_type',
        'interface_version', 'addr_ton', 'addr_npi', 'address_range',
    )

    def __init__(self, command, **kwargs):
        super(BindTransmitter, self).__init__(command, need_sequence=False, **kwargs)

        self._set_vars(**(dict.fromkeys(self.params)))
        self.interface_version = consts.SMPP_VERSION_34
```

As you can see the `BindTransmitter` contructor (`__init__`) truncates the `system_id` to a max length of 16 and `passsword` to 9. Not sure why this was done this way.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the official SMPP protocol spec. According to the spec the `system_id` is supposed to max 16 and `password` is supposed to be 9 for connection type: `transmitter`.

The following is the screenshot of this spec:
[image]

This is the [link](http://docs.nimta.com/smppv50.pdf) to the spec if anyone is interested.

So in conclusion, the library implementation of the spec is correct.